# JQuery Timepicker timezone

Tags: jquery, timezone, datetimepicker

My users have a timezone setting which they provide at sign up. I want the timepicker (currently using [Trent Richardson's](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)) to utilize that timezone. For example, if the system time (of the user, not server) is 1730 hrs IST but the timezone setting is specified as GMT, then when the user clicks on *Now*, the time should get set to 1200 hrs, instead of system time. Is this achievable without an ugly hack? Using the timezone config has not helped. Thanks.